# How to get and display container width

Tags: javascript, php

Hey guys I would like to find my container width and display it inside css.

I was doing it with PHP to get the image width, but I actually need the container width.

Here is the code

```
<style>
@media only screen and (min-width: 999px) {#media{margin-left:-<?php echo $image_data[1] / '2' + '100'; ?>px}}
</style>
```

So I need to get .imagecontainer width / 2 + 100

That will be my margin-left

Comment: Why not just percentages?

Comment: left:50% and I need a margin-left

Answer (score 0):

Why Do you not use jquery to solve this problem? Just use

```
   $('.imagecontainer').width();
```

When you have got the width display the container so that the container is not shown until it is positioned correctly.

Comment: Yes I want that. How can I combine jquery with that piece of code
#media{margin-left:-<?php echo $image_data[1] / '2' + '100'; ?>px}